# How to connect the power planes of 2 PCBs with the least stray inductance?

Tags: power-supply, pcb, pcb-design, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics

By the nature of my project, I am designing 2 power electronic boards that are supposed to have its high power main voltage and ground plane connected together. Can you recommend a type of connector or a connection design that will provide the least stray inductance?[image]

Comment: Do you mean Board 1 must supply Power and Gnd to Board 2?  What voltage, and how many amps?  Many 0.025 inch square pins are rated for 1 or 2 or more Amps, you might be able to just use a small number of each of those.

Comment: Yes, board 1 must supply power and gnd to board 2. The voltage should be around 40V with 20A current. I'm looking for type of connectors that will introduce the least amount of stray inductance. I want the connection to be as good as though the power and ground planes of both boards are seemingly one. Are there any methods or connection designs to do this?

Comment: Connectors have, per pin, about 1 nanoHenry inductance per 1milliMeter of length. As does any piece of wire, ignoring the mild natural-log(length/diameter). Use some bypass capacitors on the PCB, to establish "local batteries" on your PCB2.

Comment: thanks, what capacitance should I consider? Is there a set of criteria to follow to identify the capacitance required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bank of 8 pins each for power & Gnd like one of these would do it, with 3A (or more) current rating per pin
https://www.digikey.com/products/en/connectors-interconnects/rectangular-connectors-headers-male-pins/314?k=male+header&k=&pkeyword=male+header&sv=0&pv1989=0&pv88=26&pv90=2&pv2024=9&pv91=623&sf=1&FV=ffe0013a&quantity=&ColumnSort=-66&page=1&pageSize=25

Select a suitable female socket to mate it with.
https://www.digikey.com/products/en/connectors-interconnects/rectangular-connectors-headers-receptacles-female-sockets/315?k=female+header&k=&pkeyword=female+header&sv=0&pv1989=0&pv88=32&pv564=2&pv1790=1&pv2172=i2&sf=1&FV=ffe0013b&quantity=&ColumnSort=0&page=1&stock=1&pageSize=25